# Pyspeech, two unknown inputs from two lists

Tags: python, list, speech-recognition, sapi

I'm playing with pyspeech 0.5.2 on python 2.7.9 and hit a wall.
You can listen for specific words by giving pyspeech a list of words to listen for, like this:

```
color = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'brown'...]
phrase = speech.input("I'm listening", color)
print phrase
```

It will only proceed when it recognizes any of the words in the list above.
What I'm trying to achive, needs two separate lists. The words I really have in those lists are too wierd for speech recognition to guess without the provided list, and the lists are to big to make a combination-table if-statments.
Let's say I'm using the color list above, and I want to assign extra commands to each of them:
*search* *green*. or *paint* *green*.

Those words, *search* and *paint*, amongst other words is in another list, and I need to combine one word from each list to make a two-word sentence. How would I do that?

Here's a visualisation of what I want:

```
color = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'brown'...]
commands = ['search', 'paint', 'show'...]
phrase = speech.input("I'm listening", commands, color,)

---saying green & paint out loud---
>>> phrase
['green', 'paint'] # OR 'green paint'
```

Alternatively it would also help if I got one word from the color list, and let the recognition guess the other, something like this:

```
phrase = speech.listenfor  ->  'open %s'
#where %s would be replaced by anything after open
prhase = speech.listenfor  ->  color + "%s"
#one word from color, and %s would be replaced with anything I said after
```

(The 'code' above is more of a representation)

Comment: Are you looking for a big list of color+command combinations? You can get that with `sentences = [' '.join((noun, verb)) for noun in color for verb in commands]`, but I'm not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: @EricAppelt It's kind of what I'm looking for. But while having 400+ words in color, and 20 in commands, this list would be massive. Therefore I'm looking for a way to get pyspeech/pywin to input two lists, recognize one from each as output, instead of one list one word as output.

Answer (score 0):

In the internals [pyspeech](https://github.com/michaelgundlach/pyspeech/blob/master/speech.py) uses grammar interface to set grammar from the list of phrases:

```
    grammar.DictationSetState(0)
    # dunno why we pass the constants that we do here
    rule = grammar.Rules.Add("rule",
            _constants.SRATopLevel + _constants.SRADynamic, 0)
    rule.Clear()

    for phrase in phraselist:
        rule.InitialState.AddWordTransition(None, phrase)

    # not sure if this is needed - was here before but dupe is below
    grammar.Rules.Commit()
```

You can modify this part of code to add more complex rules, this is not possible outside of pyspeech through the public pyspeech API. Alternatively you can just use winapi directly without pyspeech.

Comment: If I'm not completely wrong the `grammar.DictationSetState(0)` (zero paramter) means that it does not allow for free word recognition, which I can modify if I want a command + unknown -> "close %s". I guess I could say two words with a long enough pause to create a space as an input, split by space, then go for grammar on each word for it's own separate list.

Comment: It is not possible to mix dictation and grammar. You can use either dictation or grammar. If you know the list of items beforehand (like you wrote 400+ items) you can still use grammar, it should give you a good accuracy.

Comment: I see. But how could I achieve the following: "What's the weather in %location%", where location is free words recognition? (no list in this example) Do I have to listen for anything, then check if "What's the weather in" is included, and extract the following word? Thanks for help so far.

Comment: If you do not have exact list you can use dictation mode